# I don't understand how to switch from Tensorflow to Tensorflow Lite on a project taken from GitHub

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to create a .tflite model from a CycleGAN taken from GitHub (https://github.com/vanhuyz/CycleGAN-TensorFlow).

I am very new in this field and I do not understand how to expose the .pb model (which I have already created from the checkpoints) in a .tflite model.

I tried with `tflite_convert` but without any result, also because I don't know the parameters to insert as `--input_arrays` and `--output_arrays`.

Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the TFLiteConverter python api here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api and use SavedModel as your model input format. Otherwise, you can provide the input and output tensor names or your pb model as input_arrays and output_arrays.